# Query Haversine with JDO

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, geospatial, jdo

I need help to do this query with JDO:

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(lat_t) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(lng_t) )
   + sin( radians(lat_t) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM Stores HAVING distance < 25 
ORDER BY distance
```

I'm trying to consult with proximity coordinates, and much internet searching, I found this algorithm Haversine. [The source is Google](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geospatial).

This is what you need:

```
public static ArrayList<User> getUsers(double lat, double lng, double distance) {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
    Query query = pm.newQuery(¿?¿?¿?);

    ...

    return users;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From: http://db.apache.org/jdo/jdoql_methods.html

```
When writing the "filter" for a JDOQL Query you can make use of some methods on the various Java
types. The range of methods included as standard in JDOQL is not as flexible as with the true Java
types, but the ones that are available are typically of much use.
```

You should lookup your values and apply whatever methods you desire on these values.

For the ordering part, the `Query` interface has a method called `setOrdering`, pass to it `yourColumn ASC|DESC` (i.e. `ASC` OR `DESC`)